# What is a good shopping cart gem for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to implement basic shopping cart functionality in my Rails app....are there any good gems that will make this process simple?

i.e. I want the shopper to be able to add products and quantities to their checkout, and I want the admin to be able to add new products to the store (and edit/delete existing ones).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a wide range of payment and eCommerce gems covered at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=23).

A list of gems can also be found at [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/e_commerce) and [here too](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=payment).

Also, not covered, you can use the Saas product [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for...places where I can go read up about the different options. I tried RubyGems.org, but that didn't turn up too much :(

Comment: Couldn't earlier, but just did :) Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

There are few:

- https://github.com/spree/spree
  Engines, plugins, big, no good i18n
- https://github.com/piggybak/piggybak
  Engine, plugins, no i18n, new project and still a lot of changes
- https://github.com/nimbleshop/nimbleshop
- http://www.ror-e.com/
- https://github.com/potionfactory/potionstore/ 
  Not an Engine

Answer (score 7):

maybe you can try https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart
That gem good for simple cart. Maybe you need little modify if you need update cart functionality

Answer (score 1):

The list of a few is good, 
and now there is one more engine: [RubyClerks](http://rubyclerks.org)

It's small and simple, but all that small businesses needs. 
And so it uses much less memory than others.